# How can I get and post File with thymleaf + Spring boot

Tags: file, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

How can I set the input file for the edit form with Spring Boot + thymelaf?
I try to use the MultpartFile class, but I only can get its values...
This is the data transfer class:

```
public class DocumentoCommand {
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private String dataEmissao;
    private MultipartFile arquivo;
    private String tipoDocumento;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<input th:field='*{arquivo}' type="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle file upload.

```
<input type="file" id="doc" name="doc" />

public String add(@ModelAttribute Documnet document, @RequestParam(value = "doc", required = false) MultipartFile[] doc){}
```